# How to remove new line characters from NSString in a webservice response?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I am presently getting a Webservice Response which contains many new line characters. I have tried the following approaches but still i am not able to eliminate the New Line Characters.

1)

```
responseString = [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

2)

```
responseString = [responseString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

3)

```
NSRange foundRange = [responseString rangeOfString:@"\n"];
    if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound)
        [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"
                                            withString:@""
                                               options:0 
                                                 range:foundRange];
```

My Webservice respsonse is in this format.

```
META NAME="ColdFusionMXEdition" CONTENT="ColdFusion DevNet Edition - Not for Production Use."?      


    wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>{"MESSAGE":"","CODE":1,"RESPONSE":{"FILENAME":"CustomerSkillsIntro","PLAYLIST":[{"TIMEOUT":73,"TITLE":"Greet","QUESTIONNUMBER":1,"TIMEIN":71,"VALIDRESPONSE":1},{"TIMEOUT":77,"TITLE":"Have Name Tag","QUESTIONNUMBER":2,"TIMEIN":74,"VALIDRESPONSE":1},{"TIMEOUT":83,"TITLE":"Greet","QUESTIONNUMBER":3,"TIMEIN":78,"VALIDRESPONSE":1},{"TIMEOUT":112,"TITLE":"Helping Do My Job","QUESTIONNUMBER":4,"TIMEIN":109,"VALIDRESPONSE":1},{"TIMEOUT":134,"TITLE":"Greet Happily","QUESTIONNUMBER":5,"TIMEIN":131,"VALIDRESPONSE":1},{"TIMEOUT":144,"TITLE":"Stay cheerful when resident is crabby","QUESTIONNUMBER":6,"TIMEIN":141,"VALIDRESPONSE":1},{"TIMEOUT":154,"TITLE":"Bond with the new resident","QUESTIONNUMBER":7,"TIMEIN":151,"VALIDRESPONSE":1},...................
```

My requirement is to capture only the part of the string from `{"MESSAGE":"","CODE":1,` till the end. But i am getting too many white spaces and new line characters before the required part.

Comment: is there a possibility that you also get `\r` characters in webservice response? Some services will return `\n\r` (combination of `CR`+`LF`). Also one way would be to find first accurance of `{` and last accurance of `}` and then deal with data between them.

Comment: Can u please help me find how to do that?

Comment: i've added answer with code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could simplify your problem by taking string from first occurance of `'{'` to last occurance of `'}'`.

Code below ensures the result you want with different approach. Why go trough the process of removing white space if you say you need only the part "from `{"MESSAGE":"","CODE":1,` till the end.`"

```
NSRange start = [responseString rangeOfString:@"{"];
NSRange end = [responseString rangeOfString:@"}" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *result = nil;

if ((start.location != NSNotFound)&&(start.location != NSNotFound))
{
    NSRange resultRange = NSMakeRange(start.location,end.location - start.location + 1);
    result = [responseString substringWithRange: resultRange];
    NSLog (@"returning with result: %@", result);
}
else 
{
    NSLog (@"abort mission");
}
```

Comment: Where in this code are we eliminating the occurences of new line characters and white spaces?

Comment: @PradeepReddyKypa: we don't since it looks there aren't (from your example) if you crop out the string between first { and last }. Try it out and see if you get the desired result.

Comment: I have not yet triend this...will let u know if this works...Thanks a lot for the help...